# Infer nested function parameter types from containing object

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics, type-inference

I've got myself hitting a bit of a brick wall with Typescript. I am attempting to build a command-parsing utility, and would like to add type hints within configuration objects.

Consider the following;

```
interface Argument {
  type: 'string' | 'number'
}

interface Command {
  label: string
  arguments: Record<string, Argument>
}

// --

export default {
  label: 'execute-task',
  arguments: {
    'task_name': {
      type: 'string'
    }
  },
} as Command
```

Now consider that I would like to add a 'handler' function within this object;

```
type HandlerOptions<...> = ...

interface Command {
  label: string
  arguments: Record<string, Argument>
  handler: (options: HandlerOptions<...>) => void
}

// --

export default {
  label: 'execute-task',
  arguments: {
    'task_name': {
      type: 'string'
    }
  },
  handler(options) {
    console.log(options)
  },
} as Command
```

I would like to get type inference on the `options` object at `console.log(options)` line above, such that;

- to begin with; `typeof options` resolves `{ task_name: unknown }` or similar
- in a more advanced version, it resolves to `{ task_name: string }`, though I expect this will be simple once my previous goal is achieved.

What I'm struggling with is defining the `HandlerOptions<...>` type in the above example, such that it resolves the actual object properties, instead of the `Command` generic, which returns an empty record.

Looking at the docs, the primary direction I've been trying is variations of the following (indexed types);

```
type HandlerOptions<C extends Command> = {
  [key in keyof C['arguments']]: ...
}
```

Attempted with `ThisType<Command>`, 'rebuilding' the type using utility types, and wrapping the configuration object in a function that returns a computed type... but that doesn't help for type hinting in the original object itself.

The closest I have been with this resolves to `{ [x: string]: ... }` or an empty object.

I'm therefore wondering;

- Is this even possible?
- If yes, what's the nugget that I'm missing here?
- If not, what would be a possible alternative for similar developer experience?

Thank you!

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/Nd8gXN) work for you? If yes, I'll write an answer explaining; If not, what am I missing?

Comment: @wonderflame That seems like exactly what I'm looking for, thank you! I'm particularly curious about the `TypeMap` -- I'm a little lost around there, which is where this seems to differ from Brandon's answer below

Comment: your arguments have type of `"string" | "number"`; however you expect the arguments to be the `string` or `number`. Simply without the `TypeMap` then end type would be a `"string"` or `"number"`. `TypeMap` converts the string to the type. `"string" -> string`, `"number" -> number`. Should I write an answer?

Comment: A bit more digging and I mostly get it, thanks. I'm still wondering the way the infer ternary block works here; if my understanding is correct its purpose is to catch invalid type map values?

Comment: The ternary part (`extends infer R ? { [K in keyof R]: R[K] }: never`) is actually optional. It is used to only make the end result look more informative. Without it, `option` will look like: `HandlerOptions<{task_name: {type: "string";};}>`

Comment: I saw that you accepter Brandon's answer, should I remove mine then?

Comment: Thanks for the writeup, accepted as answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently, there is no way to do that directly with the type you want. Instead, we should add a generic parameter to `Command` interface, which will represent the `arguments`:

```
interface Command<
  T extends Record<string, Argument> = Record<string, Argument>
> {
  label: string;
  arguments: T;
  handler: (options: HandlerOptions<T>) => void;
}
```

For the `HandlerOptions` we will need a map to convert string literal of the argument to the actual type:

```
type TypeMap = {
  string: string;
  number: number;
};
```

In `HandlerOptions` we are going to use [mapped types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) to achieve the desired type:

```
type HandlerOptions<T extends Record<string, Argument>> = {
  [K in keyof T]: TypeMap[T[K]["type"]];
}
```

Example:

```
// type Example = {
//   argument1: string;
// }
type Example = HandlerOptions<{ argument1: { type: "string" } }>;
```

We will also need a some function that would accept a `command` and return it. The only purpose of this function will be to infer the type of the `arguments`:

```
const getCommand = <T extends Record<string, Argument>>(command: Command<T>) =>
  command;
```

Usage:

```
getCommand({
  label: "execute-task",
  arguments: {
    task_name: {
      type: "string",
    },
  },
  handler(options) {
    // HandlerOptions<{
    //  task_name: {
    //     type: "string";
    //  };
    // }>
    options;
  },
});
```

To make the type of the `options` more readable we may use the the following utility type:

```
type Prettify<T> = T extends infer R ? { [K in keyof R]: R[K] } : never;

type HandlerOptions<T extends Record<string, Argument>> = Prettify<{
  [K in keyof T]: TypeMap[T[K]["type"]];
}>;
```

With this the type of the `option` for the previous case will be:

```
{  
  task_name: string;
}
```

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.0.4#code/C4TwDgpgBAKuEFkCGYoF4oG8BQUoGdgAnASwDsBzALgOPIoG5coyBXAWwCMIia2ueTAL5Ns5YDwBmSAMbQAgkQocIZYFmahINAESFSlHVAA+UHf25Edw7Ni3QACkQjBgJSSAA8MAHzpYUBAAHhJkACb4UOSSPFAASlAA-FhQANoA0lFkUADWECAA9pLxALo0cRklUEJQfBAAboK29lAAEkjhADY8APJgbgVk+N6BIaoR8RAyBURhnvr0ADRQisrsqsA+fhhOLm4enjh4GVm5+UWwZbDwyGCpMJWpOvY6JSXCPqLiUrLQAMIFdjsDpzZgwUahCZxKYzOYLSjLVYqNTbSbTWbzOgIlZKZGbbB+I5QTpIbidGjwxjMJC49ZqfA0GBMPAACxB3V4UAAFAV+iRBgy2uzenyBd4fABKdB+eoFEhhGzYaZDdQUFwAoEg-wjYKQyLQ9FwrEURG0jZbLnTTXhGga4HhcVStA+ZhW+0K2xq4B2kFcokksm6YJTVgSAC0wCQ+ByOkW1LN9JoRLwkejAH0yEh1knmHgU-BdJTY7nqnG8EIy1A2V0eDzRUMpcmoLyBkNmXmAPQdqAAPUSzAr2CEEtEQA)

Answer (score 0):

So I *think* I understand what you're looking for, but I apologize if I got it wrong. I modified your types and added a generic `createCommand` helper method that allows the type of `options` to be inferred:

```
interface Argument {
  type: "string" | "number";
}

type HandlerOptions<Args extends Record<string, Argument>> = {
  [key in keyof Args]: any;
};

interface Command<Label extends string, Args extends Record<string, Argument>> {
  label: Label;
  arguments: Args;
  handler: (options: HandlerOptions<Args>) => void;
}

function createCommand<Label extends string, Args extends Record<string, Argument>>(
  label: Label,
  args: Args,
  handler: (options: HandlerOptions<Args>) => void
): Command<Label, Args> {
  return {
    label,
    arguments: args,
    handler,
  };
}

const testCommand = createCommand("execute-task", { task_name: { type: "string" } }, (options) => {
  console.log(options.task_name);
});
```

When writing the function I passed as the `handler` argument to `createCommand`, the type of options was inferred - Intellisense suggested `task_name` after typing "options.".