# Interface properties to share the same same generic type

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I'm trying to do something similar as in the question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76351424/infer-nested-function-parameter-types-from-containing-object). I want to extend Argument with a couple of methods that all share the same type:

```js
type ArgumentType = "string" | "number"

type Argument = {
  type: ArgumentType;
  d?: () => ArgumentTypeI
  s?: (v: ArgumentTypeI | undefined) => ArgumentTypeI[] 
}
```

where `ArgumentTypeI` is an actual instance of `ArgumentType` type defined in `TypeMap`

What to modify in the [the example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.0.4#code/C4TwDgpgBAKuEFkCGYoF4oG8BQUoGdgAnASwDsBzALgOPIoG5coyBXAWwCMIia2ueTAL5Ns5YDwBmSAMbQAgkQocIZYFmahINAESFSlHVAA+UHf25Edw7Ni3QACkQjBgJSSAA8MAHzpYUBAAHhJkACb4UOSSPFAASlAA-FhQANoA0lFkUADWECAA9pLxALo0cRklUEJQfBAAboK29lAAEkjhADY8APJgbgVk+N6BIaoR8RAyBURhnvr0ADRQisrsqsA+fhhOLm4enjh4GVm5+UWwZbDwyGCpMJWpOvY6JSXCPqLiUrLQAMIFdjsDpzZgwUahCZxKYzOYLSjLVYqNTbSbTWbzOgIlZKZGbbB+I5QTpIbidGjwxjMJC49ZqfA0GBMPAACxB3V4UAAFAV+iRBgy2uzenyBd4fABKdB+eoFEhhGzYaZDdQUFwAoEg-wjYKQyLQ9FwrEURG0jZbLnTTXhGga4HhcVStA+ZhW+0K2xq4B2kFcokksm6YJTVgSAC0wCQ+ByOkW1LN9JoRLwkejAH0yEh1knmHgU-BdJTY7nqnG8EIy1A2V0eDzRUMpcmoLyBkNmXmAPQdqAAPUSzAr2CEEtEQA) given by @wonderflame to support my example above?

EDIT:

I've updated the example with what I would like to achieve [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.0.4#code/C4TwDgpgBAKuEFkCGYoF4oG8BQUoGdgAnASwDsBzALgOPIoG5coyBXAWwCMIia2ueTAL5Ns5YDwBmSAMbQAgkQocIZYFmahINAESFSlHVAA+UHf25EdTPABMI01gBtgAfhoAKAJToAfFFYyAGsyAHsAdzIoAHpoqHtHFygANyQnVghsIWxsLWgABSIIYGASSRAAHhh-DBgoCAAPCTJbfChySR4oACUoVywoAG0AaXaooIgQUMkegF0abpHZqCEoPghkwRy8qAAJJBanHgB5MFLQsnwq+qbVVp6IGVCiWwr9egAaKEVldlVgXw1KCFYqlcoVHB4EZjKATKYzGDzWDwZBgQYwJaDHR5HSzWbCXyicRSWTQADCoXY7AOr2YdUazXu3Uez1e70oXx+KjUQOZTxebzoHO+Sm5AOw-khUCcSG4Tho7MYzCQor+anwNBgNigAAsaUdeFAPKEziQLhq9vqTqbzVVfD40P5kqESLZhDknpd1BRihSqTT0FBrgy7m0+azBQYKJzVf9AR4nv6WjQ-dSWnaHb5mIm026Peb1DJ2LZAz7gKmaR4pTK5bpGo9WBIALTAJD4II6D7K2PqmhSvCt9sAfTISD+feYeAH8F0is7k6nCSQzmAnkzGinm5icSKwFYRCiOiXK5SaQyRliBB1oWcJe4UGOwwXm93+6iAHZ39urzenCXXweUDhCqZD0FAz4rAuQhdng0HMHqhw8MaNqXD4-ZQCa5yXNqeCXgAeq4zBwUIXiiJ6hDxA4y4uAAame0AYEWtgAHQqr8-z4Mxg5BCOY4QMxx4uN437sKwFH3oq2BAA)

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/N9Qy3N) work for you? If yes, I'll write an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: also `What to modify in the the example given by @wonderflame to support my example above?` has invalid code

Comment: I've updated my question to hopefully be more clear.

Comment: @wonderflame I've added an addendum to the question. Hope it shows what I wish to achieve.

Comment: Il looks kind of a limitation, but does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/w6z6Yw) work?

Comment: It seems to work! There is one additional issue - I can't assign the resulting cmd to Command. For example: `const c: Command = cmd`

Comment: what should be the type of `c`' `options` in such cases?

Comment: I'm storing commands in `type Definition = { name: string;  paths: Record<string, Definition>;  cmds: Record<string, Command>};` so when a command like `ip netwok interface add ...` comes in I can recursively drill into definition to find command. 

Now that command args and default are typesafe I would like to add that command into `const root: Definition`. This is where I'm stuck: https://tsplay.dev/w2kabN

Comment: Does [this](https://tsplay.dev/mba0dN) work?

Comment: Yeah, that works. Would you like to create an answer so i could accept it?

Comment: Yup, will do in a bit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why exactly, but the compiler can't infer types correctly with [discriminated unions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#discriminated-unions) and works only if the type is defined as single object with union values:

```
type Argument = {
  type: keyof TypeMap;
  default?: () => TypeMap[keyof TypeMap];
};
```

By doing this we will fix the return type of the `default` function to the correct type, however, now we are not type-safe since we can return `number` where the type is `string` and the closest that I could get is to check in the type whether the return type is same as the type from `TypeMap`:

```
interface Command<
  T extends Record<string, Argument> = Record<string, Argument>,
> {
  label: string;
  arguments: { [K in keyof T]: ReturnType<NonNullable<T[K]['default']>> extends TypeMap[T[K]['type']] ? T[K] : never }
  handler: (options: HandlerOptions<T>) => void;
}
```

Note that we use [NonNullable](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#nonnullabletype), since `default` is optional and we use [ReturnType](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#returntypetype) to get the return value an check if it is the same as it is in the `TypeMap`. If the type is correct we don't do anything to the values, otherwise, we assign the value to `never`, which will raise the error.

[Link to Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.0.4#code/C4TwDgpgBAKuEFkCGYoF4oG8BQUoGdgAnASwDsBzALgOPIoG5coyBXAWwCMIia2ueTAL5Ns2UJCgBBIhQ4QywdFmYSINANYQQAewBmseMjBM8AEwh6krADbAA-DQAUASnQA+Q5GMBtLboM4bxQAXWFRNSgABSIIYGASPRAAHhhPDBgoCAAPYAUzfChyPR4oACUoeywoHwBpIrIof31ykJoyupCoISg+CAA3QTFIgAkkMjMbHgB5MASdMnxUrNz8wrKIAGMdIjNkwlJKABppWXlFd3To2PjElJw8Ooam7RaYNq9EFB8YTp8AcjU-xCYWwQnconIeSIVk20AAwjp2OxxntmJkcnkJustjs9gd6CcZHJ2ApgFcNttdvs6MdTiSye4jthPA8oDYkNwbDQCZRTFAkGdSYp8DRMDV6uQXgFYB8NsBWEQyEEIMkAHILNW2DmcKapP7-CxWWzAYGXFZYgqfXy-WohAFAkGVWCdXosAalITMAAWqKmvCgTh0cxIC1FUDGE39s3mi1S7jcaE8-R0JDMwjE2G2iyUFDiiORqOUyWzhFgFrW5Vx1N5FCJQsZ7ic20LExoBZRE3jifczBbnfTYlLSk27DMyjzwA7qKcbJ1EG5UH+OS2rDyAFpgEh8Bp-sy8IKGSKxcw8FudwB9MhIUknvD3qBqGj-Wt70-3o3WOzOHsqB8Pm5FUaAB2YD+QfIR93vSD33PDQrxvCAACY73-J8l1fKCH0-E0fw8P9-zwQClSXUD-nA6CsO6ZlmBgvBfSjHggxDMM3DZPBg1jfAKIAeh4qAAD17Fo5khBcURhygHC7AANSQGxWGgDBRzMAA6Q9zmAfBVLghDSSQ1TpOAVwGCgPioHYVgy24WhDgobAgA)